# Adding Bank Account data to stripe not saving to API or database table

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

**Issue:** The Bank Account data in the form isn't saving to the Stripe API (Stripe::Account), possibly because it's not being correctly or successfully Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_token)

**Question:** What in my code is causing the retrieve to not work or is the issue something else, such as not having webhooks correctly set up, or incorrect JS?

**My Thoughts:** I am assuming it's not the controller, but the way the JS is set up as I am not well versed in JS.  I found an example application on GitHub using Stripe Connect the way I want it to function and used it as a reference to build my BankAccount controller, view/form, and JS.

This is the sample application for reference I have used to help me set this up: https://stripe-marketplace-demo.herokuapp.com/

**How it's set up:** I have Users table ; users sign up and get inputted into this User Table.  I then have a StripeAccounts table; users (current_user) can create a StripeAccount, the stripe account token is saved as acct_id within StripeAccount >> the user_id (from User table) is associated with the StripeAccount. The stripe_account token is also saved in the User table under stripe_token.  Once a stripe_account is created and saved, they are redirected to fill out the BankAccount form << This is where my issues are.  The bank account information isn't saving and most likely due to a failure to retrieve.  Reasoning below.

Here's the entire Bank Account Controller:

```
class BankAccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new

    unless current_user.stripe_token
      redirect_to new_user_stripe_account_path and return
    end

    begin
      @stripe_account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_token)

    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      handle_error(e.message, 'new')

    rescue => e
      flash[:error] = e.message
    end
  end

  def create

    unless params[:stripeToken] && current_user.stripe_token
      redirect_to new_bank_account_path and return
    end

    begin
      stripe_account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_token)

      stripe_account.external_account = params[:stripeToken]
      stripe_account.save

      flash[:success] = "Your bank account has been added!"
      redirect_to dashboard_path

    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
       flash[:error] = e.message


    rescue => e
       flash[:error] = e.message

    end
  end
end
```

I have the stripe_accounts saving correctly with the stripe token saved under "acct_id" in the StripeAccounts table, and the same token saved as "stripe_token" under the Users table in relation to the correct user_id.

I am new to rails (about a month in) and very new to Stripe so the following is only assumption:  I am assuming the "@stripe_account = Stripe::Account.retrieve(current_user.stripe_token)" in the new method isn't retrieving anything.  Does this rely on webhooks? That I may not have set up correctly? I have tried doing this through ngrok, but to no avail.  Although, I receive no errors on page in html.
I would then assume I'm getting stuck at the code in the create method:

```
  unless params[:stripeToken] && current_user.stripe_token
      redirect_to new_bank_account_path and return
    end
```

Because when i press submit, the page simply reloads and nothing saves to the API.

Here's the view/form I am submitting along with the JS:

```
<%= content_for :page_title, "Add a new bank account" %>
<% content_for(:header) do %>
  <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.payment/1.4.1/jquery.payment.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Set your Stripe publishable API key here
    // Stripe.setPublishableKey("<%= ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>");
    var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_3v1234567896LyWMYKE1f0B8');

    $(function() {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');
      $form.submit(function(event) {
        // Clear any errors
        $form.find('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks:
        $form.find('.submit').prop('disabled', true).html("<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i> Adding bank account...");
        // Request a token from Stripe:
        Stripe.bankAccount.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);


        return false;
      });
    });
    function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {
      var $form = $('#payment-form');
      if (response.error) {

        $form.find('.errors').text(response.error.message).addClass('alert alert-danger');
        $form.find('.' + response.error.param).parent('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false).text('Add Bank Account'); // Re-enable submission
      }
      else { // Token was created!
        $form.find('.submit').html("<i class='fa fa-check'></i> Account added");

        var token = response.id;

        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

        $form.get(0).submit();
      }
    }
  </script>
<% end %>

<div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <form action="/bank_accounts" method="POST" id="payment-form">
      <div class="errors"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Country</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg" id="country" data-stripe="country">
              <option value="US">United States</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Currency</label>
            <select class="form-control input-lg" id="currency" data-stripe="currency">
              <option value="usd">USD</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" id="routing_number_div">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="routing_number_label">Routing Number</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg bank_account" id="routing_number" type="tel" size="12" data-stripe="routing_number" value="110000000" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label id="account_number_label">Account Number</label>
            <input class="form-control input-lg bank_account" id="account_number" type="tel" size="20" data-stripe="account_number" value="000123456789" autocomplete="off">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary btn-custom submit" type="submit">Add Bank Account</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you see in the JS: `// Stripe.setPublishableKey("<%= ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] %>");`
I have tried with that, but apparently it's not up to date anymore.  Just for testing purposes, I have simply included the publishable key directly within the JS and not in credentials just yet until I figure it out.

Here is my console when I submit the form:

```
Started POST "/bank_accounts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-10 14:32:11 -0500
Processing by BankAccountsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"l69UBGkzwcel7JH34+TDbsfQ9Xjkiogu+emWm+8+0iVQfKh9AIxDaXp0yMhjFkUVznHeJYwXeVmdBVSI2XjArg=="}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/bank_accounts/new
Completed 302 Found in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/bank_accounts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-10 14:32:11 -0500
Processing by BankAccountsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
  StripeAccount Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "stripe_accounts".* FROM "stripe_accounts" WHERE "stripe_accounts"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/bank_accounts_controller.rb:6
  Rendering bank_accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered bank_accounts/_bank_account_form.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered bank_accounts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (3.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 218ms (Views: 212.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

the e.message reads as follows:

```
Invalid external_account object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See API docs at https://stripe.com/docs'
```

but the e.message only appears on page reload and not when the form is submitted.  Only once I submit, and then reload the page, it appears.

I having nothing set up within the BankAccount model, either does the example app i used as a reference.

**Extra information:** For Users and StripeAccount, I have them nested, which is why you will see new_user_stripe_account_path... BankAccount isn't nested to anything.

Message from Browser Console:

```
Error: The selector you specified (#card-element) applies to no DOM elements that are currently on the page.
Make sure the element exists on the page before calling mount(). v3:1:10186
t
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:10186
oi/this.mount<
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:79868
Gt/<
https://js.stripe.com/v3/:1:23367
<anonymous>
http://localhost:3000/assets/stripejs.self-8c2ad75855f867e5280e1a173e994f83fb5afc997847456669b8cbe0b24fae1f.js:31:1
[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIContentSniffer.getMIMETypeFromContent]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: resource:///modules/FaviconLoader.jsm :: onStopRequest :: line 181"  data: no]
onStopRequest
resource:///modules/FaviconLoader.jsm:181:16
InterpretGeneratorResume self-hosted:1257:8 next self-hosted:1212:9
```

Comment: Because you are getting an error like "must be a dictionary or a non-empty string" , I suspect your bank account token is never getting passed to your back-end at all --- in fact i don't see it in the log you shared `Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"l69UBGkzwcel7JH34+TDbsfQ9Xjkiogu+emWm+8+0iVQfKh9AIxDaXp0yMhjFkUVznHeJYwXeVmdBVSI2XjArg=="}` --- try adding some debugging to your JS --- console.logs in your stripeResponseHandler, a breakpoint before the form submit (check that a hidden stripeToken input really exists in your form using browser dev tools inspector)

Comment: I added the Browser Console when i press submit.  Other than that, do you think the rest of the code is okay?

Comment: BTW, "check that a hidden stripetoken input exists"... is that something I'll see in the Browser console...? and in the update, it's not there if so?

Comment: So it looks like, from what i understand, is the JS is for Stripe V2 and not Stripe V3  you can see the differences here: V2:https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#collecting-bank-account-details ----V3:https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference#collecting-bank-account-details ----- so im trying to migrate it over to v3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like the JS was to blame.  It was somewhat wrong and out of date, and a few things weren't matched up with my controller.

Here's the correct JS for S v3
**JS on view page** (i believe this NEEDS TO BE UNDER the form; could be wrong):

```
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_WUSo123456789PWU8kh');

  function setOutcome(result) {
  var successElement = document.querySelector('.success');
  var errorElement = document.querySelector('.error');
  successElement.classList.remove('visible');
  errorElement.classList.remove('visible');

  if (result.token) {
    // In this example, we're simply displaying the token
    successElement.querySelector('.token').textContent = result.token.id;
    successElement.classList.add('visible');

    // In a real integration, you'd submit the form with the token to your backend server
    var form = document.querySelector('form');
    form.querySelector('input[name="token"]').setAttribute('value', result.token.id);
    form.submit();

  } else {
    errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    errorElement.classList.add('visible');
  }
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var bankAccountParams = {
    country: document.getElementById('country').value,
    currency: document.getElementById('currency').value,
    account_number: document.getElementById('account-number').value,
    account_holder_name: document.getElementById('account-holder-name').value,
    account_holder_type: document.getElementById('account-holder-type').value,
  }
  if (document.getElementById('routing-number').value != '') {
    bankAccountParams['routing_number'] = document.getElementById('routing-number').value;
  }

  stripe.createToken('bank_account', bankAccountParams).then(setOutcome);
});
```

**And the correct Create for the BankAccount controller:**
(or this at least works, i may be fixing this up a bit after this)

```
def create
    unless params[:token] && current_user.stripe_token
      redirect_to new_bank_account_path and return
    end
    begin
      token = params[:token]
      stripe_account.external_account = params[:token]
      stripe_account.save
      flash[:success] = "Your bank account has been added!"
      redirect_to dashboard_path
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
      # handler_for_rescue(e.message, 'new')
      flash[:error] = e.message
    # Handle any other exceptions
    rescue => e
      # handle_error(e.message, 'new')
      flash[:error] = e.message
    end
  end
end
```

In the form, I also pass the following which may or may not be needed, I will do testing on this later on after i post this.:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, form_authenticity_token -%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :stripeToken, current_user.stripe_token -%>
```

I don't believe :stripeToken is needed... but auth is